# How can I set the default container in the Skin Template?

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin, skinning

You can configure the container template on the site, on page or in the container settings. But can I set the default container in the skin?

Is there a way to set the default container in the footer as NoTitle template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article it talks about it:
http://www.psdtodnn.com/Blog/tabid/76/EntryId/23/Configuring-the-default-container-for-all-modules-in-a-pane.aspx